# Why does the Continuum Hypothesis make an ideal measure on $\mathbb R$ impossible?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

On the page 43 of *Real Analysis* by H.L. Royden (1st Edition) we read: "(Ideally) we should like $m$ (the measure function) to have the following properties:

1. $m(E)$ is defined for each subset $E$ of real numbers.
2. For an interval $I$, $m(I) = l(I)$ (the length of $I$).
3. If $\{E_n\}$ is a sequence of disjoint sets (for which $m$ is defined),
   $m(\bigcup E_n)= \sum m (E_n)$."

Then at the end of page 44 we read : "If we assume the Continuum Hypothesis (that every non countable set of real numbers can be put in one to one correspondence with the set of all real numbers) then such a measure is impossible," and no more explanation was given.

Now assuming the Continuum Hypothesis I am not able to see why such a measure is not possible.  Would you be kind enough to help me?

Comment: Please do **not** write all-caps. You should edit this to fix it...

Comment: @Kamram: To explain, on the web, writing in all capitals [is considered shouting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). You are basically yelling at people.

Answer (score 13):

This is a consequence of Ulam's theorem: If a finite countable additive measure $\mu$ is defined on all subsets of a set of cardinality $\aleph_1$ (the first uncountable cardinal) and vanishes on all singletons, then it is identically zero.

This is the version of the theorem from the book of [Bogachev](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540345132) (1.12.40), the [original result](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm16/fm16114.pdf) is a bit stronger. Anyways, under CH, $\mathbb{R}$ has cardinality $\aleph_1$, so the theorem applies to $\mathbb{R}$. I'm pretty sure this is what Royden refers to.

Comment: I would argue that the form of Royden's remark is rather Banach-Kuratowski's negative solution to Lebesgue's measure problem under CH, see their article *[Sur une généralisation du problème de la mesure](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm14/fm14110.pdf)* on which Ulam's paper expands. Note also that relaxing the countable additivity condition 3. to finite additivity, there is such a function $m$, as was shown earlier by Banach: *[Sur le problème de la mesure](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/fm/fm4/fm412.pdf)*.

Comment: The result can also be found in Oxtoby book.

Answer (score 9):

I refer you to the MathOverflow question "[Does pointwise convergence imply uniform convergence on a large subset?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45784/does-pointwise-convergence-imply-uniform-convergence-on-a-large-subset)" for proofs and references for the following:

> Assuming the Continuum Hypothesis, there exists a sequence of real-valued functions on $\mathbb R$ that converges pointwise to a function on $\mathbb R$ but does not converge uniformly on any uncountable set.

Suppose there were a function $m:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb R)\to[0,\infty]$ satisfying the three named conditions.  Then $m$ is a measure on $\mathbb R$ for which every subset of $\mathbb R$ is measurable.  Let $(f_n)$ be a sequence of real-valued functions on $[0,1]$ that converges pointwise to some function.  By Egorov's theorem, there is a set $E\subseteq [0,1]$ with $m(E)>0$ such that $(f_n)$ converges uniformly on $E$.  The fact that $m(E)>0$ implies that $E$ is uncountable.  Since $(f_n)$ was arbitrary, this implies by the above cited result that the Continuum Hypothesis does not hold.

---

In light of Michael's answer, I want to mention that the hypothesis 2, that $m(I)=l(I)$ for each interval $I$, could be replaced by the following two properties:

(a) For all $x\in\mathbb R$, $m(\{x\})=0$.

(b) There exists $X\subseteq\mathbb R$ such that $0<m(X)<\infty$.

Then the same argument as above would apply with such an $X$ in place of $[0,1]$.