# Explicit indexing of countable ordinals by sequences of integers?

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

What I really want is this: A sequence $P_0$, $P_1$,... such that each $P_n$ is a countable partition of $\omega_1$, $P_{n+1}$ is a refinement of $P_n$, and such that if $A_n\in P_n$ for all $n$ and $A_{n+1}\subset A_n$ then $\bigcap A_n$ contains at most one point. Just to give it a name, let's say that last condition says that $(P_n)$ is an "injective" sequence of partitions.

This is equivalent to the existence of a injection from $\omega_1$ into $\omega^\omega$, that notation referring to the set of all maps from $\omega$ to itself. Of course such an injection exists, the question is whether there's an "explicit" one.

There's a natural elegant way to construct $P_1$ from $P_0$ and then $P_2$ from $P_1$, etc. Say $P_0=\{I_n:n\in\omega\}$ and assume each $I_n$ is uncountable. Then each $I_n$ is order-isomorphic to $\omega_1$; this isomorphism together with our partition $P_0$ of $\omega_1$ induces a partition $\{I_{n,j}:j\in\omega\}$ of $I_n$, and now we let $P_1=\{I_{n_0,n_1}:n_0,n_1\in\omega\}$. Now we use $P_0$ again to define a partition of each $I_{n_1,n_1}$, etc.

A $P_0$ such that this construction gives an "injective" sequence $P_0,P_1,\dots$ would be cool. Alas what strikes me as the natural choice of $P_0$ [fails](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1759578/question-regarding-countable-ordinals#1759610). (For a minute I thought that the fact that the construction fails for one $P_0$ implies that it fails in general. When I think about the details this becomes less clear; if you feel like asserting that it must fail in general because it fails for one $P_0$ please include a little explanation.)

An explicit injective sequence of partitions by some other construction would be fine...

Comment: No, there are no explicit injections, in the sense that the existence of any of them requires the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Well, I'll stop looking for one then.

Comment: I'm unclear  about something. If $\omega_1$ is singular, then there is such "natural" sequence of partitions. But it is consistent that $\omega_1$ is singular, and there is no injection into $\omega^\omega$, see the Feferman-Levy and the Truss models for the perfect set property. If the proof of equivalence is correct under the assumption that $\omega_1$ is regular, then it is consistent there is no such injection, assuming the consistency of an inaccessible cardinal. In this case, there is indeed no natural choice for $P_0$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila When I said that the existence of that sequence of partitions was equivalent to the existence of that injection I wasn't worrying about whaether I was using AC...

Comment: (1) If you want something explicit, you have to worry about choice; and (2) if you have choice then you obviously have an injection from $\omega_1$ into the reals, so why worry now about explicity?

Comment: @AsafKaragila People who don't do set theory sometimes use AC without realizing they're doing so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are attempting is not possible in general. Here is a counterexample: It is consistent (modulo large cardinals) that dependent choice holds, but full choice fails, and the club filter is an ultrafilter on $\omega_1$. Since the club filter is countably complete, it follows that in such a model, if we partition $\omega_1$ as $\bigcup_n B_n$, then exactly one $B_n$ contains a club. If we have a sequence $P_0,P_1,\dots$ of partitions of $\omega_1$ as you want, for each $n$ there is exactly one element of $P_n$ that contains a club. Call it $A_n$, and note that $A_{n+1}\subseteq A_n$ for all $n$. But then the intersection of the $A_n$ also contains a club. (A quick proof of the last claim goes by noting that the assumptions ensure that $\omega_1$ is regular and that we can simultaneously pick clubs $C_n\subseteq A_n$ from each $n$. But then one easily checks that $\bigcap_n C_n$ is also club.)

Comment: I have to go right now, will get back to this...

Comment: By the way, the equivalence you claim between the existence of such a partition and the existence of injections from $\omega_1$ into the reals also uses the axiom of choice. The point is that in the Feferman-Lévy model where ($\mathbb R$ is a countable union of countable sets and) $\omega_1$ has countable cofinality there is a partition as you want (as described by Asaf in the now-erased answer), but there is no injection of $\omega_1$ into $\mathbb R$.

Comment: In your first paragraph,I don't see what you want with $ \cap A_n$ . This notation means the common intersection of the members of $A_n.$  If $A_n$ is a non-empty set of ordinals then $\cap A_n=\min \{x:x\in A_n\}$ which is a one-point set iff $\min A_n=1.$

Comment: Re: Andres Caicedo's comment above: At some point you need to assume that an injection $f:\omega_1\to P(\omega)$ exists, but this is a "non-explicit" assumption. That is, $f$  cannot be described in ZF. (Unless $1=0$ is a theorem of ZF.)

Comment: @user254665 Hi. I believe your first comment is addressed to David. When he writes $\bigcap A_n$, he means $\bigcap_{n\in\omega}A_n$.

Comment: Yes .It was addressed to David. Thank you.

Comment: @AndrésCaicedo Thanks. I find that somewhat convincing. And thanks for clarifying what I meant by $\bigcap A_n$ while I was gone...