# A 'measure' on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory, real-numbers

**Question:** Is there function $\mu : \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}) \to [0, \infty]$ with the following properties:

1. $\mu$ is countably additive. (on disjoint sets)
2. $\mu((a, b])) = b-a$, i.e., it extends the usual length function.
   ?

Notice that I am not putting the usual **translation invariant** condition.

The reason for this question is to try to understand what leads to the failure of existence of an actual measure on power set of $\mathbb{R}$. Is the translation invariance enough of an obstruction? An answer to this question will resolve this. From the standard counterexample : Vitali Sets it is not clear since we use all the aspects of a measure to get to the contradiction.

Of course if we further remove the condition that $\mu$ extends the usual length function (2) then the dirac measure is an example but so far I have no counterexample when only translation invariance is removed.

**Addition**: One way to see that size of $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ is not a problem by itself, since the set of all lebesgue measurable sets has the same cardinality as $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$. This can be seen by taking a lebesgue null subset of $\mathcal{R}$ which has same cardinality as $\mathbb{R}$, for example, the **Cantor Set**.

Comment: This question is relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2728935/is-there-a-countably-additive-set-function-m-on-mathscrp-mathbbr-such?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @AlexOrtiz  Is that not an answer to this question?

Comment: @GEdgar I suppose it does. I missed the search word countable additive and maybe that's why the question didn't show up in my search .