# Constructing measure as described by Royden Real Analysis

Tags: measure-theory

So in the very beginning of measure theory in Royden(3rd ed). He says that it is not possible to come up with an extended real valued function m on $\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R})$ assuming continuity hypothesis(any non-countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is in one to one correspondence with it)  with the following properties-

i) For an interval I, m(I)=l(I), where l(I)= length of interval

ii) If $<E_n>$ is a sequence of disjoint sets then, $m(\cup E_n)=\sum_n m(E_n)$

My work- Firstly, it is easy to see that measure of any countable set is $0$, since measure of a point would be zero(as we can take a sequence of intervals decreasing to that point showing in effect that its measure is arbitrarily small and for countable will follow from (ii)). This would lead us to the conclusion that any set with positive measure must not be countable and hence using CH(cont hyp.) that it must be in bijection with $\mathbb{R}$.

But from here i am not sure how to arrive at the desired conclusion.

I thought maybe a contradiction to the existence would be a set having 2 possible values for measure or no possible value, but since bijective functions would not preserve measure of sets(eg $[0,1]$ and $[0,2]$ are in bijection but have different measures from (i)) I am not able to comment much on this.

**Information available at stack exchange**

Additionally, this question has been directly asked before in [Why does the Continuum Hypothesis make an ideal measure on $\mathbb R$ impossible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95964) But I believe there should be a simpler answer than the ones proposed here since it is asked in the very beginning and does not give any reference for such complicated train of thought.

Also, this one asks why existence of such a set function is not possible to know without continuum hypothesis- [Is there a countably additive set function $m$ on $\mathscr{P}(\mathbb{R})$ such that $m(I) = l(I)$ for every interval $I$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2728935)

Comment: Do you require $l$ to be translation-invariant?

Comment: @AnginaSeng No it is not necessary

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model

Comment: @AnginaSeng I think ZFC+axiom of choice model is independent of continuum hypothesis.

Comment: @AnginaSeng I think ZFC+axiom of choice model is independent of continuum hypothesis(see [here](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/continuum-hypothesis/)) and what you are proposing is that ZFC exclusive of axiom of choice is giving such a set function in solovay model, but what is the contradiction with continuum hypothesis? Also, I think the author wants contradiction assuming ZFC+axiom of choice+continuum hypothesis. See 2nd hyperlink in q above for discussion on why it might not be possible to give without continuum hypo.

Comment: ZFC+axiom of choice=ZFC, because  C in ZFC is the axiom of choice.

Comment: @AlexRavsky, yes sorry about that. When I'm writing ZFC i actually meant ZFC exclusive of axiom of choice(it should be clear from context since I'm deliberately adding axiom of choice everywhere).

Answer (score 1):

[image]In the preface(to 2nd edition) to Royden book, Royden admits that he is making some polemical(meaning: of or involving strongly critical or disputatious writing or speech) remarks, most of them appearing in footnotes(the info in this question is also in a footnote).